# HTTPS error - "You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server."

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have an eCommerce WordPress site using woo commerce. Now my hosting company "Heart Internet" provide free SSL certs however the map a subdomain to my domain to achieve this.

Real domain
http://mywebsite.com/

SSL Version
https://web110.secure-secure.co.uk/mywebsite.com/

So this means if I want to use SSL for my checkout page I need to link to this url.
https://web110.secure-secure.co.uk/mywebsite.com/checkout

However doing so provides me with the error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) Server at web115.secure-secure.co.uk Port 80
```

So I would imagine this is something to do with .htaccess but I am not sure.

If I go to this url:
https://web110.secure-secure.co.uk/mywebsite.com

It actually does display the home page, however minus any images or css styles and my console is full of failed to load resources error messages.

AFter contacting my hosting company they have said its due to how the site itself is configured. But this is just a simple wordpress website, nothing fancy going on.

Does any one know what I can do?

EDIT:: Image of heart internet ssl

[image]

To clarify my question is not about css/images not showing up on homepage, its about the fact i cannot reach any other page on my website without getting the error - You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

Comment: it does not Redirect u on ur site. do a `Tracert DOMAIN` in ur cmd-prompt. i think the endpoint is still `secure-secure.co.uk/mywebsite.com/checkout/index.php` and not ur Server/domain

Comment: what is a Tracert DOMAIN? the end point will be that, there is not a redirect, it just means i have to go to the https://secure....  which is like a copy of my site

Comment: windowsKey -> cmd -> hit ENTER .-> a black console Pops up. type in `tracert YOURDOMAIN` and see what the endpoint Server is. /// https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314868 with `yourdomain` i mean https://web110.secure-secure.co.uk/mywebsite.com/checkout`

Comment: and which domain should i tracert, this - secure-secure.co.uk/mywebsite.com/checkout/index.php

Comment: unable to resolve target system name

Comment: i assume `mywebsite.com` and `secure-secure` are just synonyms to hide ur realnames of ur Domains ? if yes u have to trace the Real Domains....

Comment: I do not know, but i have added an image to the question which may help explain it to you

Comment: did u read what the Image says ?? they now use `ad-aquatics.com`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125887/discussion-between-virepo-and-kikitheone).